# Open map at specific coordinates not working on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm building an application with the functionality of sending specific pre-determined (but dynamic) coordinates to the user's map app so he can trace a route to it.

Currently, I'm using:

```
String coordinates = String.format("geo:0,0?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(coordinates) );
startActivity( intent );
```

However, when it does open the map, instead of the requested location I get a "no results for [latitude], [longitude]" toast and my current location instead.

It's certainly not an issue with the coordinates themselves as manually searching for them work just fine and printing the request Uri show that it's correctly constructed. Surprisingly, only sending the first two digits of both coords sort of works and, while doesn't send me where I want to, does not give the toast error message.

Do I need to do any extra formatting when passing the values or some other thing?

I'm using them raw, -23.561261 and -46.681212 for example, am located in Brazil if that makes any difference and, yes, I do have to send the coordinates as sadly the data is inconsistent with the formatting of the actual addresses.

UPDATE: As it turns out, the code is fine, it works on my razr-i, however, in the Galaxy Express I used for the original tests, it's still a no go.

Any idea of what is going on? Both devices are running Android 4.1.2

Comment: Did you ever resolve this - I'm having exactly this problem on certain devices.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I did. Don't remember what was the error, but I just posted the working code in my answer; check it out if it still matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't quite remember what the error *was* since it's been so long ago, but long story short, here's the working code:

```
String coordinates = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + latitude + "," + longitude;

Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(coordinates) );
startActivity( intent );
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct,

the values that you send are double?

```
    double latitude = -23.561261;
    double longitude = -46.681212;
    String coordinates = String.format("geo:0,0?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
    Intent intentMap = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(coordinates) );
    startActivity( intentMap );
```

must be something similar to load directly in your browser the url:

[http://www.google.com/maps?q=-23.561261+-46.681212](https://www.google.com/maps?q=-23.561261%20-46.681212)

Comment: Yes, apparently I am indeed doing everything correctly, just tested it on another device, a Motorola razr-i this time and it works like a clockwork. However, on the other device, a Samsung Galaxy Express, I still get the nonsensical error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in locale. Your code will work on any phone if you call format() like this:

```
String coordinates = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
```